# RecurrenceTable is not honoring FullSimplify

Tags: simplifying-expressions, recursion

I define a function `nextK` and compute the first three terms in a recurrence as follows:

```
nextK[k3_] := Expand[FullSimplify[3 + k3 + 2 Sqrt[2 + 3 k3]]]
G[y_] := nextK[G[y - 1]]
G[1] := 3
Table[G[i], {i, 3}]
```

with the output

[image: first three terms in the sequence]

However if I use `RecurrenceTable`

```
RecurrenceTable[
  {a[n + 1] == nextK[a[n]], a[1] == 3},
  a, {n, 1, 3}
]
```

I get the following:

[image: same terms, as output by recurrencetable]

Note that the third element has not been simplified.  It should be the same as the third element of the previous computation.  It's as if the `FullSimplify` in the definition of `nextK` has not been honored.  What am I doing wrong?

**(Update)** Clearly, `FullSimplify` could be run once the table is complete, but for non-trivial tables (say 10 or 20 elements rather than just 3), the pre-simplification expressions can be huge.

Comment: `In[713]:= nextK[a[n]]

Out[713]= 3 + a[n] + 2 Sqrt[2 + 3 a[n]]` Which means `FullSimplify` will not be seen in `RecurrenceTable`. You may improve things if you use `RSolve` in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For my purposes I should have been using something like `NestList`.

```
NestList[nextK, 3, 5]
```

[image]

gives exactly what is expected.

When using `RecurrenceTable` I did not appreciate that it is a solver, rather than an iterator.  The use of `==` as opposed to `=` should have tipped me off.

As a solver, `RecurrenceTable` needs to set up a well defined set of recurrence definitions.  In my case, it executes `nextK` symbolically to get `nextK[a[n]]3 + a[n] + 2 Sqrt[2 + 3 a[n]]`.  `Expand` and `FullSimplify` have been applied, but in the symbolic case they have no effect (unlike in the numeric case using exact expressions).

A simpler example gives confirmation.  We define a new function `nextL` that adds a random integer:

```
nextL[x_] :=x + RandomInteger[{1,20}]
```

Then

```
seq=RecurrenceTable[{a[n + 1] == nextL[a[n]], a[1] ==x}, a, {n, 1,5}]
(* {x,16+x,32+x,48+x,64+x} *)

Differences[seq]
(* {16,16,16,16} *)
```

shows that `nextL` is only called once, whereas in

```
seq2=NestList[nextL,x,4]
(* {x,15+x,27+x,31+x,48+x} *)

Differences[seq2]
(* {15,12,4,17} *)
```

`nextL` is called for each iteration.

Answer (score 3):

I see the same behavior in the latest version

```
$Version

(* "12.2.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (December 12, 2020)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

nextK[k3_] := FullSimplify[3 + k3 + 2 Sqrt[2 + 3 k3]];
```

Add memorization to the definition of `G`

```
G[y_] := G[y] = nextK[G[y - 1]];
G[1] := 3
Table[G[i], {i, 3}]

(* {3, 2 (3 + Sqrt[11]), 15 + 4 Sqrt[11]} *)
```

The [`RecurrenceTable`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RecurrenceTable.html) results have not been simplified. Presumably, `nextK` is first evaluated symbolically where the simplification does not change the form. Subsequent numeric values do not then have the simplification applied.

```
seq = RecurrenceTable[{a[n + 1] == nextK[a[n]], a[1] == 3}, a, {n, 1, 5}]

(* {3, 6 + 2 Sqrt[11], 9 + 2 Sqrt[11] + 2 Sqrt[2 + 3 (6 + 2 Sqrt[11])], 
 12 + 2 Sqrt[11] + 2 Sqrt[2 + 3 (6 + 2 Sqrt[11])] + 
  2 Sqrt[2 + 3 (9 + 2 Sqrt[11] + 2 Sqrt[2 + 3 (6 + 2 Sqrt[11])])], 
 15 + 2 Sqrt[11] + 2 Sqrt[2 + 3 (6 + 2 Sqrt[11])] + 
  2 Sqrt[2 + 3 (9 + 2 Sqrt[11] + 2 Sqrt[2 + 3 (6 + 2 Sqrt[11])])] + 
  2 \[Sqrt](2 + 
      3 (12 + 2 Sqrt[11] + 2 Sqrt[2 + 3 (6 + 2 Sqrt[11])] + 
         2 Sqrt[2 + 3 (9 + 2 Sqrt[11] + 2 Sqrt[2 + 3 (6 + 2 Sqrt[11])])]))} *)

seq = seq // FullSimplify

(* {3, 2 (3 + Sqrt[11]), 15 + 4 Sqrt[11], 6 (5 + Sqrt[11]), 51 + 8 Sqrt[11]} *)
```

Note that [`FindSequenceFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindSequenceFunction.html) can be used to generalize from the sequence provided by `RecurrenceTable`

```
f[n_] = FindSequenceFunction[seq, n] // FullSimplify

(* 6 - 2 Sqrt[11] + n (-6 + 2 Sqrt[11] + 3 n) *)
```

Verifying that this result is equivalent to `G`

```
And @@ Table[G[n] == f[n], {n, 50}]

(* True *)
```

However, the results of `f` must also be subsequently simplified to obtain the same form as `G`

```
f /@ Range[3]

(* {3, 6 + 2 Sqrt[11], 6 - 2 Sqrt[11] + 3 (3 + 2 Sqrt[11])} *)

% // FullSimplify

(* {3, 2 (3 + Sqrt[11]), 15 + 4 Sqrt[11]} *)
```

Comment: Thanks for `FindSequenceFunction`, I will find that handy.  But otherwise, I think you are just confirming that `FullSimplify` is not honored and it has to be applied after the sequence is computed.  The problem is that if you run the `RecurrenceTable` for even a small number of entries like `{n, 1, 10}` its printout will explode, and I worry that there is a time penalty for running a `FullSimplify` on such a massive expressions.  The fact that `RecurrenceTable` works with `==` definitions (instead of `=` definitions) makes me think it does not run the way we assume.

Comment: The closed-form, i.e., `f[n]`, does not "explode" for any value of `n`. And if you want a simpler form, `Simplify` will suffice.

Comment: I simplified my `nextK` for the purposes of the question, so I'm not sure a closed form exists.  But if it does, `RSolve` and `Simplify` will certainly do the trick.  If it doesn't, I might be better off defining recursive function `G` and using `Table`